# Any MySQL client on my local machine freezes if not talking to server for a while

Tags: mysql

On my local machine I use a MySQL client to connect to a remote MySQL server (an Amazon EC2 instance). I tested many many client, but all of them freezes (I have to force close them) if I try to perform any operation after some minutes I did anything (idle).

I'm asking if the server can perform some type of timeout, or if is there a reason it can freeze on some query performing.

I have to say the website running on the server continue to work without any problems, so there is something wrong in the remote connection.

Here is my **my.cnf**: http://pastebin.com/S4PmA3j3

During freeze CPU is not used on the server:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-48-239-133:~$ top
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  686 mysql     20   0  874m  66m 5100 S  0.0 11.3  36:55.78 mysqld
```

And connections are ok:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-48-239-133:~$ netstat -tup
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 ip-10-48-239-133.:mysql MY.LOCAL.IP:59633       ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 ip-10-48-239-133.:mysql MY.LOCAL.IP:58964       ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0    384 ip-10-48-239-133.eu:ssh MY.LOCAL.IP:45745       ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 ip-10-48-239-133.eu:ftp MY.LOCAL.IP:54109       ESTABLISHED -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a timeout on the connection table in a stateful firewall in between the clients and server. You don't say what OS is running on the clients. If it's Linux, then try reducing [tcp_keepalive_time](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/)

Comment: Client is running on a Xubuntu 12.04 in my office network (can't tell you know about firewalls here), server is running on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on Amazon EC2 behind standard Amazon firewall. I will try to change *tcp_keepalive_time* asap. Thank you.